# virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-fileprovider

**Please don't mark it duplicate before reading it**

I have searched through all the links on stackoverflow and Github for a possible answer but still am getting the same error.

Here is the Manifest file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider android:authorities="com.example.aditya.pdf_report"
        android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:readPermission="com.company.aditya.pdf_report.READ">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

Here is Java file:

```
    File filelocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/pdf_report/" + reportname.getText().toString().trim() + ".pdf" );
        Uri path;
        path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, getPackageName(),filelocation);
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// set the type to 'email'
        emailIntent .setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");

        emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
// the mail subject
        emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Here is the Branch Visit Report - Human Resources");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send email..."));
```

here is file-paths.xml:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="pdf_report" path="pdf_report/"/>
</paths>
```

here is my package name:

```
com.example.aditya.pdf_report
```

Here is where the Pdf is saved on my phone:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/pdf_report"
```

**I have followed all the links but I think its the file-paths.xml where I am writing wrong stuff**

Comment: what is `fileprovider` in manifest ?

Comment: That was a typo. That should be the name my application. But now I get this error Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/pdf_report/whfnscs.pdf

Comment: "Please don't mark it duplicate before reading it" No one is doing that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `file-path.xml` as below. It may be work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked. But I have a question, How do we actually write in this? because none of the answers never mentioned what to actually write in that.

Comment: All the details with very nice explanation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider).

Comment: You can mark accepted and up vote if issue is resolved. because It may help to others also.